# MySQL - how to permanently store cache?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, query-optimization, myisam

I have a million row table with a lot of specific queries that slows everything down. Each query has to execute on every click a user makes.

Currently, I am storing the results of my intensive queries into a $_SESSION. Just because the MySQL cache gets deleted after a few different queries.

**Is it possible to somehow permanently store repetitive queries better than $_SESSION?** Even after user 1 did a query, and later a user 2 does the same repetitive query even days (?) after?

The table barely gets new records..like.. ever. So it's basically a table for 99.99% reading, and not writing.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE `campaign__companies` (
`id` int(21) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`business_id` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`form_id` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
`spec_ids` int(6) DEFAULT '0',
`spec_path` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`country_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
`region_id` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`city_id` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`code_id` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`profile_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`has_email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`email_price` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`has_phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`phone_price` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`is_active` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`failed_request` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`failed_captcha` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`date_added` int(21) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`date_registered` int(21) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`date_checked_pre` int(21) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`date_checked_captcha` int(21) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `country_id` (`country_id`),
 KEY `has_email` (`has_email`),
 KEY `has_phone` (`has_phone`),
 KEY `spec_ids` (`spec_ids`),
 KEY `country_region` (`country_id`,`region_id`),
 KEY `country_region_city` (`country_id`,`region_id`,`city_id`),
 KEY `country_region_city_code`
 (`country_id`,`region_id`,`city_id`,`code_id`),
 KEY `spec_path` (`spec_path`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=950047 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: FIle cache? Memcache?

Comment: The previous person already gave a ling for Memcache. Can you explain File cache? Or is it a PHP thing? Because, it's not a bad idea, but I want to be able to do less using MySQL...File cache, ofc, is good, but its my last resort

Comment: Let's see if we can speed up the queries.  Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  With luck this will be an easy fix, and a lot easier than building a caching layer.

Comment: I updated the question... but the explain does not fitt.... should i give you something more specific?

Comment: I d prefer using **memcached** or **redis** to store results, according to the query. However, you can tune mysql query cache to store much more as well. See mysql docs for **query_cache** variables. Though, memcached is the most popular way and even facebook uses it with mysql to store billions of data.

Answer (score 0):

If increasing the size of query cache isn't possible, you might want to consider something like [memcache](http://memcached.org/) or similar options (Redis!). This lets you write values to a caching server and retrieve them extremely quickly. As you're using PHP you'll find it has a very simple API: just point it at a memcache server (which could be the same machine as your MySQL server if needed), then read and write key/values.

Note: memcache is not permanent either, but it is certainly good for a longer term.